# What is meant by "He Seconds Me"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I asked my friend to refer me to one of his friends. He replied "I referred you. He Seconds Me". Can someone tell me what is the meaning of "He Seconds Me" here?

Comment: Welcome to ELU Sankar. This is a General reference question which can be answered with a dictionary: [second](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/second?q=second) as a verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/second?q=second):

> **second** *verb*
>   [*with object*]
>   formally support or endorse (a nomination or resolution or its proposer) as a necessary preliminary to adoption or further discussion:
>   *Bridgeman seconded Maxwell’s motion calling for the reform*
>      express agreement with:
>      *her view is seconded by most Indian leaders today*

"He seconds me" means either "He has formally put another referral in as well," or "He agrees with me."

Generally *second* as a verb is used in committees and other fora with set procedures: a motion which is to be voted on must be proposed [put forward] by its primary supporter and then seconded [openly supported]  by someone else.

There are also *seconds* in boxing, who *second* (support) each fighter.